# How do I have an event filter a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a twitter clone in JS + jQuery for a pre-course to a development program, so if this is an obvious fix - let me know!
I have a problem I'm unable to solve: "click on username, page returns with that user's last tweets".

The only thing I could come up with is, an event handler on the `<a>` tag filter the page. However I'm vastly inexperienced and unclear in how to proceed.

Any ideas?
note- I removed some code for brevity.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $body = $('body');
$body.html();

var stream = function() {
    var index = streams.home.length - 1;
    while (index >= 0) {
        var tweet = streams.home[index];
        var $tweet = $('<div class="tweetbody"></div>');
        $tweet.text(': ' + tweet.message);
        $tweet.appendTo($body);
        index -= 1; 

        var link = $('<a>', {
            text: tweet.user,
            href: '#',
        }).prop('outerHTML');
        $tweet.html('@' + link + ': ' + tweet.message);

    }

    };
```

Here's the `<a>` tag event:

```
 //click on a username to see that user's timeline. 

    $('a').on('click', function() {
        console.log("a tag is clicked ");
        console.log(this);
    });




   }(); 
    }); //end document ready body
```

Comment: If the data (tweets + users) are on your server, my best bet would be an `ajax` call. Other solution would be to build the anchor's `href` with parameters (for open it in a new page, and go from there)...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Andrew.  The specs state we should be able to build this with JS + jQuery on this index page. I'm pretty stumped on how to make this work. I was thinking this click handler could clear the page then add the a tag's username's twitter feed? Or is that just more work than it needs to be? (If it can even be done at all)

Comment: Not entirely clear what behavior you are looking for. A better explanation of expectations would help Use of data attributes on that html will help you if you are wanting this as single page application

Comment: I'm looking for the click handler to change the page. It would remove the other user's tweets and the selected users tweets would remain. if this is a backwards approach or if click handlers don't work that way, let me know. shooting in the dark type of thing here.

Comment: I tried to use the click event handler, to shape it to my needs, before, but honestly, I found it tedious and rather messy. But this is only my opinion. I posted an answer with my proposal. Hope it does help.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I can't have it open a new page, it has to refactor whats there unfortunately.

Comment: Then the second option (with `ajax`) should be ok. Do you need help with that? Or you can't (read: not allowed) to use `php` at all, all the data being kept in an object/array in js?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use php or ajax calls, just plain ol' vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

In the on click function you could perhaps do either of the two things, so go to another page, like redirecting to a new page

```
    //click on a username to see that user's timeline. 

    $('a').on('click', function() {
        //console.log("a tag is clicked ");
        //console.log(this);
        window.location = '/some_file.php?get_tweets='+tweet.user;
    });
```

or, use an ajax call to do the same:

```
    //click on a username to see that user's timeline. 

    $('a').on('click', function() {
        //console.log("a tag is clicked ");
        //console.log(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/some_file.php",
            data: {
               'user' : tweet.user
            },
            success: function(msg) {
                $body.html(msg);
        });
    });
```

In both cases `some_file.php` should format the content.